# Search specific extension filenames that contain a particular string in Bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to search in one Linux folder all the py files that contain the string "2" in their names.

I began with the following code :

```
for file in /home/sig/*.py;
do echo "$file is present"; 
done
```

But I don't see how to add the string search condition.

Could you help me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo /home/sig/*2*.py
```

or

```
ls /home/sig/*2*.py
```

or

```
for file in /home/sig/*2*.py; do
  echo "$file was present"  # inherent race condition
done
```

The loop is not terribly reliable, as the file may exist when the shell performs the glob expansion to get the list of files, but it may not exist by the time the 'echo' is executed.  This is probably an academic concern for your use case, but can often be a source of real errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for both help and explanations !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`:

```
find /home/sig/ -type f -name "*2*.py"
```

BTW, `sh` != `Bash`. You tagged your question with [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) but you are asking about `Bash` in your question.

**EDIT:**

Execute every file:

```
find /home/sig/ -type f  -name "*2*.py" -exec {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you ! Another question : is it possible to put that snippet into a `for` loop ? I'd like to execute the py file as soon as the file is found into my folder.